# use Jquery load to load content in adiv?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, load

I have a div called test and mvc action in the client controller

The view:

```
<input id="B1" type="button" value="test" />
    <div id="test">
</div>
```

The controller

```
public string testout()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

I'm using jquery to update the div

```
$("#B1").live("click", function() {
    $("#test").load("/client/testout");
    return false;
});
```

The first time I click the button I see the date and time in the div test.  The second time nothing changes.

Comment: Is it possible that your action is being cached?

Comment: try using `$("#test").load("/client/testout?" + new Date().getTime());` to make sure the action is not cached

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#B1").live("click", function() { 
 
                $("#test").load("/client/testout"); 
 
            return false; 
        }); 
});
</head>
<body>
    <input id="b1" type="button" value="test" />
    <div id="test">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing this in your jQuery code before any loads occur:

```
$.ajaxSettings.cache = false; // or $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

This prevents the client from caching the request. If that doesn't work, the problem is the server giving you a cached output.

Comment: thank you thats work great with me 
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC it is a good practice for actions to return `ActionResult`. Try modifying your code like this and see if it makes any difference:

```
public class ClientController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult TestOut()
    {
        return Content(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "text/plain");
    }
}
```

and your js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#B1').live('click', function() {
        $('#test').load('/client/testout');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the significance of the return false? Does the .live() event bubble in some weird way?

Comment: if `#B1` is an anchor (which we don't know here as the OP didn't show the markup) when you click on it it will simply follow the link and redirect to another page leaving no chance for the AJAX call to execute.

Comment: B1 is a div the code work fine in the first click but the second click i expect the date will be updated nothing happen and the old date still appear in the div b1 and the debuger didn't hit the testout action